# An anagram rebus

Tags: visual, rebus, anagram

Here is an **anagram rebus.** Find the words in the rebus and use it to find a name of a place.

[image: Anagram Rebus]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's

> Washington DC.

which is an anagram of

> chat sing down

Answer (score 2):

I got

> [Hastings Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hastings_Castle)

which is an anagram of

> Teals sing chats.

I'm no expert in the visual aspect of this, but I think they qualify, depending on environmental conditions.

Comment: nope, incorrect